# Unity D-Assembly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reverse-engineering, bytecode, cil

I am trying to reverse engineer my own game. A game written from the youtube "Brackeys", he has a tutorial series. The Cube is a game, where a constant force is pushing a cube to pass objects. I added a bit more functionality, however. Now I am trying to "Break my game". I want to know how someone could steal my source code and to protect it. I am using dotPeek from JetBrains.Now the actual question. When we write something in unity it is translated in an IL. For those who have stumbled upon this thread and are just curious, this is how it looks like.

```
// [16 5 - 16 65]
IL_0000: ldarg.0      // this
IL_0001: call         instance class [UnityEngine.CoreModule]UnityEngine.Transform [UnityEngine.CoreModule]UnityEngine.Component::get_transform()
IL_0006: ldarg.0      // this
IL_0007: ldfld        class [UnityEngine.CoreModule]UnityEngine.Transform FollowPlayer::player
IL_000c: callvirt     instance valuetype [UnityEngine.CoreModule]UnityEngine.Vector3 [UnityEngine.CoreModule]UnityEngine.Transform::get_position()
IL_0011: ldarg.0      // this
IL_0012: ldfld        valuetype [UnityEngine.CoreModule]UnityEngine.Vector3 FollowPlayer::offset
IL_0017: call         valuetype [UnityEngine.CoreModule]UnityEngine.Vector3 [UnityEngine.CoreModule]UnityEngine.Vector3::op_Addition(valuetype [UnityEngine.CoreModule]UnityEngine.Vector3, valuetype [UnityEngine.CoreModule]UnityEngine.Vector3)
IL_001c: callvirt     instance void [UnityEngine.CoreModule]UnityEngine.Transform::set_position(valuetype [UnityEngine.CoreModule]UnityEngine.Vector3)
IL_0021: ret
```

A simple function that transforms the camera position to follow the player. The Code to the function is the following :

```
     public Transform player;
 public Vector3 offset;

 private void Update()
 {
   this.transform.position = this.player.position + this.offset;
 }
```

So, **how would I know if I didn't build the game obviously that this field " public Transform player" takes has a reference to an object (which object)?** The assembly should know because otherwise, it should change my camera position based on something else like the obstacle.

Further, I have searched through the assembly but I don't know how assembly handles references. I know that the first pass goes and the second any forward references are "covered" so to say ...

When I go to the MetaData of this particular assembly I stumble upon something interesting (At least I think it is).

I've gone to TypeRef in hope of finding some readable references to see that this transformation takes the Coordinates of my Player and not something else.
Further down the line, we go to the TypeReferences we go to the class that we are interested in,

Second, we go to the filed we are interested in which is obviously Player.  We are greeted with some information, the important one in my opinion is Field Attributes field accesses and there we stumble upon a "Compiler Controlled" Member not referencable.

How does the assembly know which coordinates to take? it must have a reference and how can I Find that particular reference or any really.

Comment: For some reason, my Hello StackOverflow was deleted !!

Comment: Unity uses reflections to set initial values of public fileds of prefabs.

Comment: Sorry, could you be more specific and give a reference to a book or a study so I can read more about it? I understand the reflection but I want to know how does the whole process takes place?

Comment: Unity is not open source so there are no docs about how it does it, but reflections are the only way this is possible ( without messing with memory itself ) and is the workflow of pretty much everything in unity, like the editor attributes, unity methods ( which is why they arent virtual ) etc. I would assume each time `Instantiate` is called it does the reflection magic. Here is a link to read about [reflections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection), I cant do much more.